# Use class member as WNDPROC/DLGPROC with or without global

Tags: c++, winapi, callback, wrapper, wndproc

I'll go ahead and give a summary to this, how can I use a dialog procedure that is a member of a class? I am creating a window wrapper class, but `CreateDialogParam` needs a global dialog procedure, so I tried this workaround:

I have done a bit of searching on this topic. I am making a `Dialog` class which I am subclassing to make a `CMainWnd` and then instantiating that. In the `Dialog` class I have a member function defined as `INT_PTR CALLBACK Dialog::cb_proc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)`. Now, I know that windows must have a global function as a callback procedure.

So I made a `std::map<HWND,Dialog*> DlgProcs` map to associate the dialogs window handle with its Dialog class pointer.

And a `INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgMainProc(HWND,UINT,WPARAM,LPARAM)` so I could pass that to `CreateDialogParam()`. In the body of `DlgMainProc(...)` I search the map for using the `hWnd` parameter to find the `Dialog*` and return its `cb_proc(..)` member.

My problem is that none of the messages get processed, this is because the member procedure in my `Dialog` class never gets called. Even though when I put a `MessageBox()` in `DlgMainProc` inside a `if (DlgProcs.find(hWnd) != DlgProcs.end()) {` statement, the messagebox is displayed, over and over again until I have to abort the program from Visual Studio 2008. Which tells me that it is finding the `hWnd` in my map. The weird thing is it also does this if I put it in the `else` statement after that, which contradictingly tells me it is NOT finding the `hWnd` in the map.

If I put a messagebox in the `cb_proc` member function it does not get displayed at all. But during this I never get any compiler, linker, or runtime errors. When I remove the messagebox from it (as to not have to abort the program, it was just for debugging purposes) the program runs but no messages get processed, the X button does not close the program, button clicks do nothing.

---

Here is the PasteBin code: http://pastebin.com/GsGUBpZU
Btw, I have no problem subclassing this, my window is created fine, just no messages are processed, `cb_proc` just never gets called.

**EDIT:** Here is the relevant parts of the code

```
map<HWND,Dialog*> g_DlgProcs;

INT_PTR CALLBACK g_MainDlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        if (g_DlgProcs.find(hWnd) != g_DlgProcs.end()) {
                Alert("blah"); // Gets executed repeatedly
                return g_DlgProcs[hWnd]->cb_proc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        } else {
                Alert("blah"); // Removing the above alert, this gets
                               // executed repeatedly, erm, as well.. O.o strange
                return FALSE;
        }
}

Dialog::Dialog(int id, HWND parent /* = HWND_DESKTOP */) {
        _id = id;
        _parent = parent;

        // Tried this before CreateDialogParam
        g_DlgProcs.insert(make_pair(_handle, this));

        _handle = CreateDialogParam(
                (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL),
                MAKEINTRESOURCE(id), _parent,
                (DLGPROC)g_MainDlgProc, NULL
        );

        // Then tried it after CreateDialogParam
        g_DlgProcs.insert(make_pair(_handle, this));
}

INT_PTR CALLBACK Dialog::cb_proc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        Alert("blah"); // Never gets executed

        bool handled = true;

        switch (msg)
        {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
                OnInitialize();
                break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
                if (HIWORD(wParam) == 0 || HIWORD(wParam) == 1) {
                        OnMenuCommand((HIWORD(wParam) == 1), (int)LOWORD(wParam));
                } else {
                        OnCtrlCommand((int)HIWORD(wParam), (int)LOWORD(wParam), (HWND)lParam);
                }
                break;
        case WM_NOTIFY:
                {
                        LPNMHDR head = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
                        OnNotification(head->code, head->idFrom, head->hwndFrom);
                }
                break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
                OnClose(); // DestroyWindow(_handle)
                break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
                OnDestroy(); // PostQuitMessage(0)
        default:
                handled = ProcessMsg(msg, wParam, lParam);
        }

        // Convert bool to Windows BOOL enum
        return ((handled == true) ? TRUE : FALSE);
}
```

---

Does anybody know why it never gets called? Or maybe just guide me to another way to use a member function as a DLGPROC?

Comment: Please, paste your code here, because third-party pastebins couldn't be relied upon for the site's purposes.

Comment: Well, it is alot of code. Almost all of it is relevant, I thought it was bad practice to exclude parts of code because that could very well be the part of whats causing it. Well, I will select the most relevant parts I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it worked: `cb_proc` gets called.  You will miss any messages (e.g. `WM_INITDIALOG`) that get sent before `CreateDialogParam` returns.

You can fix the latter problem by adding the window handle and the object to the map in `g_MainDlgProc`.  If you get a message for an unknown window, you know it belongs to the window you're creating; put the object in a global and you can add the handle/object to the map.

Comment: Un. Believable. I tested my code a total of 7 times. It seems that I didnt use my little messagebox debugging method until after I switched to mapping the HWND and Dialog* BEFORE i called CreateDialogParam, which was the problem. I passed a NULL pointer into the map. And thanks, I think I'll put the dialog initialization code into the derived constructor since I don't know how I'd get the Dialog* since CreateDialogParam is in the constructor thus the object is not created yet

Answer (score 3):

The standard solution is to pass your `this` pointer as the last parameter to `Create,DialogParam`, stash it in `DWLP_USER` in your `WM_INITDIALOG` handler, and retrieve it from `DWLP_USER` thereafter. Basically you use `DWLP_USER` as your map.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just adding this here in case someone finds it useful; using the magic of C++11 lambdas and templates you can have a simple wrapper template that means you don't have to continually rewrite the boiler-plate code for saving and loading userdata in window and dialog box procedures.

Here's an example for the `DialogBoxParam` function, but the same technique can be applied to `CreateDialogParam` and `CreateWindowEx` as well.

```
template <typename T, INT_PTR (T::*P)(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)>
INT_PTR DialogBoxThis(T* pThis, HINSTANCE hInstance, LPCWSTR lpTemplateName, HWND hWndParent)
{
    return ::DialogBoxParam(hInstance, lpTemplateName, hWndParent, [](HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) -> INT_PTR {
        if (uMsg == WM_INITDIALOG) SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWLP_USER, lParam);
        T* pThis = reinterpret_cast<T*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWLP_USER));
        return pThis ? (pThis->*P)(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam) : FALSE;
    }, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(pThis));
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    INT_PTR MyDlgProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};

// from inside MyClass, we can show a dialog that uses member function MyDlgProc as the dialog procedure
// note it is NOT a static function

DialogBoxThis<MyClass, &MyClass::MyDlgProc>(this, hInstance,
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MYDIALOG), hWndParent);
```