# c++ dll CreateDialog error

Tags: c++, dll, callback, dialog

I got some errors in a c++ Dll, can you help me to solve it?
The errors are the following:

First error

> error C3867: '&Zfx3DDental::Graphic_Dlg_Dll': chiamata di funzione senza elenco di argomenti; utilizzare 'Zfx3DDental::Graphic_Dlg_Dll' per creare un puntatore al membro

TRANSLATON

> function called without arguments list, use Zfx3DDental::Graphic_Dlg_Dll' in order to create a pointer to the menber

Second error

> IntelliSense: l'argomento di tipo "LRESULT (__stdcall Zfx3DDental::*)(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)" è incompatibile con il parametro di tipo "DLGPROC"

TRANSLATON

> the argument of type ... is incompatible with the parameter of type "DLGPROC"

CODE (file.cpp)

```
void ZFX3DDENTALDLL Zfx3DDental::GraphicShow_Dll(HWND hWnd)
{   
winHwnd = CreateDialog(hinst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_FORMVIEW), hWnd, Graphic_Dlg_Dll); //Here I got the error!!!
if (winHwnd == NULL)
{
    MessageBox(hWnd, TEXT("Error"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
}
InitIstance(winHwnd);
ShowWindow(winHwnd, SW_SHOW);
DWORD d = GetLastError();
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Zfx3DDental::Graphic_Dlg_Dll(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
....
return DefWindowProc(hDlg, msg, wParam, lParam);;
}
```

Header

```
#define ZFX3DDENTALDLL __declspec(dllexport)
#define ZFX3D_ID long

class Zfx3DDental
{
....
public:
Zfx3DDental();
~Zfx3DDental();

void ZFX3DDENTALDLL GraphicShow_Dll(HWND hWnd);
    ....
private:
LRESULT   CALLBACK Graphic_Dlg_Dll(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
....
};
```

Maybe the problem is the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the last parameter to CreateDialog must be a global function, whereas you pass a class method. See this question for more details:

[Use class member as WNDPROC/DLGPROC with or without global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582511/use-class-member-as-wndproc-dlgproc-with-or-without-global/)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem, now it works, the callback function must be global